# Why is this crashing?

Tags: c++

This is an exercise from *Principles and Practice Using C++* You are supposed to take a word you don't like and make it "bleep" it out. I got the code to run, but before I did I wrote the code below and it crashed. I was more curious to why it was crashing? Was it the *if(words[i-1]==dislike)*? If so why doesn't the bottom if check crash the program? It's probably a simple answer, but I just was very curious to know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string temp;
    string dislike = "tuggo";

    while(cin>>temp)
        words.push_back(temp);

    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << endl;

    sort(words.begin(),words.end());

    for(int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(words[i-1]==dislike)
            cout << "BEEP DONT SAY TUGGO WHOOPS I SAID TUGG--BEEP";
        else if(i==0 || words[i-1]!=words[i])
            cout << words[i] << endl;
    }

    keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: change `if(words[i-1]==dislike)` to `if(words[i]==dislike)`

Comment: The bottom condition is not evaluated until the first one returns false.  The other answers illustrate why the first condition fails.

Comment: You might also want to replace the string literal "TUGGO" with the variable

Comment: @reformed I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: I didn't know how to word the problem besides "I don't know why this is crashing" I'm sorry.

Comment: @user2442335, you assigned the variable `dislike` with the value "tuggo"; instead of retyping the latter, use the variable instead, otherwise when you need to update, you'll have to change more than one place in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `words[i-1]`, but `i` starts at zero.  You cannot access negative indices.

Comment: _else if(i==0 || words[i-1]!=words[i])_ Why is this allowed then?

Comment: @user2442335 short circuit or. since the first part of the or evaluated to true the right hand side is not evaluated (when i = 0)

Comment: @paddy That seems odd since I imagine it all being read at once since it is an or statement. I guess I think that way because I'm not a computer. All these answers are right! Can I give credit to everybody?

Comment: @user2442335 What FDinoff said... =)  Also, I'm pretty sure the first statement should be `if(words[i]==dislike)`.  You want to check the *current* word.  The other part is just preventing repeated words from being displayed.

Comment: Yes you can up-vote anybody whose answer has helped you, and accept the answer you feel is most useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `words[i-1]` you are starting with `i = 0` so the first time around you are using a negative index which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(words[i-1]==dislike)
```

It should be crashing at this line right here during the first iteration of your loop.

If i = 0, and you are taking the index of i-1, there cannot be a negative index in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
for(int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
{
    if(words[i-1]==dislike)
        cout << "BEEP DONT SAY TUGGO WHOOPS I SAID TUGG--BEEP";
    else if(i==0 || words[i-1]!=words[i])
        cout << words[i] << endl;
}
```

Here, when the iteration begins, `i` is `0`, so it will fetch `words[-1]`, which is not valid.